# Association of User and Post

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Please Im trying to create an application where i can post like twitter, but i was the users name to be posted under their respective posts

My Post_controller looks like this

```
def index
    @posts = Post.all(:order => "created_at DESC")
    @users = User.find(:all)
    #@user_id = current_user.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
 end



def create
    @post = current_user.posts.create(:message => params[:message])
    @user.id = current_user.username
end
```

the models both have the correct association and tables are having User_id as  primary on User table and Foreign on the Post Table, how do i create a method to be a able to have my index view show the post and name.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey first of all remove all data in your table ....

then restart your server 
then it will never show that error

Answer (score 1):

you could do this in the index.html.erb

```
<% @posts.each do |p| %>
  <%= p.id %>
  <%= p.text %>
  <%= p.user.name %>
<% end %>
```

to show the post and the belonging user.

Comment: I get the error Nomethod in Post#Index, but i have name as an attribute in the user table

Comment: show us the code of the two model classes and your columns of the db

Comment: here is it                                                    `create_table "posts", :force => true do |t|
    t.text     "message"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "password_hash"
    t.string   "password_salt"
    t.datetime "created_at",    :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    :null => false
  end`
`Post.rb has - belongs_to :user` while User.rb has - has_many :user